# Warning: expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression | Trying to manipulate onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an issue when trying to manipulate onClick. I want to execute two methods (**props.showConfirmModal** and **props.onClick**) if the props.text is equal to "Update", but I have the following error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

```
const SaveButton = (props) => (
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="save-button"
        style={{
          marginTop: props.marginTop,
          marginRight: props.marginRight,
          marginLeft: props.marginLeft,
        }}
        onClick={
          props.text !== "Update"
            ? props.onClick
            : () => {
                props.showConfirmModal;
                props.onClick;
              }
        }
      >
        {props.text === undefined ? "Save" : props.text}
      </button>
);
```

onClick:

```
onClick={
       props.text !== "Update"
       ? props.onClick
       : () => {
             props.showConfirmModal;
             props.onClick;
          }
}
```

How can I make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You aren't creating a valid handler function, and you also are not invoking the callbacks correctly.

```
onClick={
   props.text !== "Update"
   ? props.onClick
   : () => {
         props.showConfirmModal; // <-- not invoked!
         props.onClick; // <-- not invoked!
      }
}
```

## Solution

Simplify your logic to be more **DRY**, i.e. don't repeat the `props.onClick` for both logic branches.

```
onClick={() => {
  props.onClick();
  props.text === "Update" && props.showConfirmModal();
}}
```

Some linters/lint rules *may* complain about the second line, if so:

```
onClick={() => {
  props.onClick();
  if (props.text === "Update") props.showConfirmModal();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your function to (else it's not a function just an expression as the error says):

```
onClick={() => {
           props.text !== "Update"
           ? props.onClick
           : () => {
                 props.showConfirmModal;
                 props.onClick;
              }
    }}
```